# Debian Linux not updating package

Tags: debian, upgrade

`apt list --upgradable` shows there's one upgradable package.

`libreoffice-sdbc-firebird/stretch-backports 1:5.4.4-1~bpo9+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:4.3.3-2+deb8u7]`

However, running `apt upgrade` does not do the trick.

UPDATE:

`apt-cache policy libreoffice-sdbc-firebird`:

```
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird:
  Installed: 1:4.3.3-2+deb8u7
  Candidate: 1:4.3.3-2+deb8u7
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.3.3-2+deb8u7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Source.list:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03]/ stretch contrib main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03]/ stretch contrib main

deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib

# Debian 8 "Stretch"
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib

#
deb [arch=amd64] http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main

# source for virtualbox backport, not avaialble in stretch
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib

#non free Opera
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
```

Comment: Please add the output of  `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` the package seem to be installed initially from Wheezy backports.

Comment: @GAD3R: in source.list I had `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib`, for virtualbox. I have commented out this line now.

Comment: Are you sure that’s *all* the output of `apt policy`? You should at least have an entry for `stretch-backports` (well, you would have had before you commented that line out in `sources.list`), and an entry for `stretch`... Actually it would be useful if you could add the contents of your `sources.list` file to the question.

Comment: That output from `policy` is only possible if you no longer have any repositories active in `sources.list`.

Comment: @StephenKitt: that's only the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice-sdbc-firebird`, not `apt-cache policy `. But things are running well now.

Comment: @Pierre `policy` was short-hand for the full command I’d asked, sorry. It’s still very surprising since plain Stretch has the package too, so it should appear there in `apt policy libreoffice-sdbc-firebird`, with a newer version than the one you have (`1:4.3.3-2+deb8u9`).

Answer (score 2):

`1:4.3.3-2+deb8u7` means the current version you have installed is the version from the main Debian 8 repositories, whereas `1:5.4.4-1~bpo9+1` is the version from backports (as indicated by `/stretch-backports`). Packages from backports are never valid installation candidates for an upgrade from the main repositories, only for upgrade from a previous version of a backported package; so while `apt list --upgradable` lists it as an upgradable package, `apt upgrade` won’t consider it for upgrade. You can see this in the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice-sdbc-firebird`.

If you really want to upgrade, run `apt install -t stretch-backports libreoffice-sdbc-firebird`; however you should only do this if you really need the updated version.