# Debian Stretch wants to upgrade main packages after enabling backports

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, backports

[Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-nginx) requires me to activate stretch-backports for its installation.
So after having

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

and doing a `sudo apt update` I get

```
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libpam-systemd/stretch-backports 237-3~bpo9+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 232-25+deb9u3]
libsystemd0/stretch-backports 237-3~bpo9+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 232-25+deb9u3]
libudev1/stretch-backports 237-3~bpo9+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 232-25+deb9u3]
systemd/stretch-backports 237-3~bpo9+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 232-25+deb9u3]
systemd-sysv/stretch-backports 237-3~bpo9+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 232-25+deb9u3]
udev/stretch-backports 237-3~bpo9+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 232-25+deb9u3]

$ sudo apt upgrade
[...]
The following packages have been kept back:
  systemd-sysv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libudev1 systemd udev
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,795 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,540 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

It really looks like it would continue updating the packages mentioned.

However, from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418315), I quote:

> Packages from backports are never valid installation candidates for an upgrade from the main repositories, only for upgrade from a previous version of a backported package; so while `apt list --upgradable` lists it as an upgradable package, `apt upgrade` won’t consider it for upgrade. You can see this in the output of `apt-cache policy`

So checking

```
$ apt policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: 232-25+deb9u3
  Candidate: 237-3~bpo9+1
  Version table:
     237-3~bpo9+1 100
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 232-25+deb9u3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     232-25+deb9u2 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

it seems like the backports version is valid for upgrade.

How can I enable upgrading from backports only for those packages which were originally installed from backports (i.e. via `apt -t stretch-backports`)?

EDIT: My `sources.list`

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to enable anything to enforce the documented behaviour for backports, but you do need to ensure that the system knows where your installed packages come from. In your case, you have a version of `systemd` from `stretch/updates`, but your sources don’t reference that, so `apt` gives the installed version of `systemd` a score of 100 which is less than or equal to the backports score (see your `apt policy` output).

To fix this, make sure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` has entries for `stretch-updates`, something like

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

You should then see `apt policy systemd` give the following results:

```
systemd:
  Installed: 232-25+deb9u3
  Candidate: 232-25+deb9u3
  Version table:
     237-3~bpo9+1 100
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 232-25+deb9u3 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /usr/var/lib/dpkg/status
     232-25+deb9u2 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I added the output of my original `sources.list` to the question. Quick follow-up: what is the difference between `stretch/updates` and your suggestion of `stretch-updates`? Is there a resource somewhere thoroughly explaining the different sources? Also, how can a package be installed without its source present?

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210405/86440) (replace `jessie` with `stretch`, it’s all still valid). I don’t know how you ended up with that version installed...